# Ubuntu 18.10 + Wireless router (TP-Link) instability issue

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.10, tp-link

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.10. Great experience so far except for the following issue:

Whenever I try to access some websites like Netflix or Mathworks, the connection to the wireless router is lost and I have to reinitialize both for them to work. It seems that when the data-flow  is high, the connection is lost, but I am not sure. The wireless router is a TP-Link model TL-WR841N(TPD) Ver: 10.0. I am using Ubuntu 18.10 on a Samsung laptop model NP910S3K. Both the laptop and the router are using the default configurations, I only changed the router passwords.

The same machine using Windows 10 and another machine (a macbook-pro late 2013) running MAC-OS High Sierra don't have this issue. They work well with the OS they came with. But I want to use linux, not windows or macOS.

I am not an expert user, I just like the idea of moving definitively to Linux. At the university, the machines work as a charm. I am having this problems just at home.

---

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [144d:4125]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Let's start by identifying the wireless device in the laptop. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: chill55, thanks for the fast response. I included it in the description

Comment: Please, someone help me. This problem is driving me crazy, having to reboot the router around 50 times a day is a deal-breaker.

Comment: If you're on firmware-6, using a [kernel above 4.14](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1670041) then perhaps some generic options like disabling power saving, disabling led flashing, disabling passive scans might help point the way?

Comment: @pbhj How do I make this modifications, could you pass me the terminal commands? I am not a linux expert, just a normal user trying to switch to it.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you said:

> Both the laptop and the router are using the default configurations

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After rebooting the computer, please give us your report.

**EDIT**: As you noted, there are many instances of 'ath10k_pci firmware crashed' in an internet search. Here is one that I suggest you try as the last post mentions a firmware change but no further complaints. https://github.com/manjaro/packages-core/issues/131

Let's try it. From the terminal, first, we back up the existing file:

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
sudo mv firmware-6.bin firmware-6.bak
```

Now we get the new firmware file:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1.c1/firmware-6.bin_RM.4.4.1.c1-00042-QCARMSWP-1
```

Any we rename it:

```
sudo mv firmware-6.bin_RM.4.4.1.c1-00042-QCARMSWP-1 firmware-6.bin
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Comment: Thank you chili555. I have made the modifications you suggested. Unfortunately the instability persists the same.

Comment: I wonder if there are any clues in the log. Please edit your question to include the result of: `dmesg | grep -e ath -e wlp`

Comment: The file is to long to include in the question. However I intentionally entered Netflix to cause the internet to go down, and there was no modification in the file before and after the internet crashed.

Comment: I'd still like to examine the log. Please post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d57ZtF5TTB/

Comment: You are experiencing regular firmware crashes. Please do: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware` Also, the log shows country code 00. Please recheck: `sudo iw reg get` Perhaps setting the country code as I recommended didn't stick. Reboot and give us a new paste as above.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/THXg3ghM3q/

Comment: One question. I travel a lot, does configuring for DK instead of 00 won't affect the connection when I am outside the country? (Sorry if the answer for this question is too simple)

Comment: Your paste looks much better! No firmware crash evident there. Does it still crash the router under load? The question of the country code while traveling is unknown to me. I suggest that you try it and report back. In case you cannot connect with 'DK', switch back instantly with `sudo iw reg set 00`

Comment: Yep, still the same instability.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/86zkvfyBp9/

Comment: I'd be interested to know if any of the firmware files are corrupt. Please paste the result of: `md5sum /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/*` and give us the link.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/46KRktCPdD/

Comment: You said: "I have the same issue using the live usb version on a macbook-pro late 2013." Does this use the same ath10k_pci driver? I suspect it is a Broadcom. Doesn't this lead us to further look at the router and not Ubuntu? Have you, for example, looked at bandwidth control? https://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-557.html

Comment: I think is some kind of compatibility between the router brand (TP-Link) and Ubuntu. I have a newer router of the same brand, and the problem is the same. With routers from other brands, I don't have problems what so ever. How do I get to know if the driver is the same? If the problem is the bandwidth limitation on the router, how can I change that? Is there a way of solving this issue inside Ubuntu, since one of the routers is not mine. The router seems to work fine for macOS and Windows, so there must be a way to configure Ubuntu to work with it as well.

Comment: Run the live session USB on the Macbook and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and tell us what it says the kernel module in use is.

Comment: I tested again the macbook (pro retina, late 2013), using now ubuntu 18.10. With the option of the proprietary drivers on I did not observe again the router instability.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6xZywVCpxS/

Comment: On the Samsung laptop, I have:
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac. I've read on some forums a huge list of people with this controller and the same problem of mine, but not solution.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DpMQFWmFB3/

Comment: Still the same instability :'(

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as this (same wireless card and same exact router model) and contacted TP-Link. They sent me the following firmware binary for the router: http://static.tp-link.com/wr841ndv11_eu_beta.zip

After updating the router with this binary I haven't had a crash since. Kudos to TP-Link for getting back to me within 24 hours over a weekend with a perfect fix, posting here for posterity.